# Routing Commands to Templated Parent

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, wpf-controls, controltemplate

I have a simple custom control that I have a `ControlTemplate` for. I can't seem to get the command from the `Button` on the control to route to the command of its `TemplatedParent`.

```
<Style x:Key="SaveButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:SaveButton}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Controls:SaveButton}">
                <DockPanel Width="65" Height="21" LastChildFill="True">
                    <Canvas DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 0 -49 0" ZIndex="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" >
                        <Image Source="Images/green-check.png" Width="16" Height="16" Visibility="{Binding IsDirty, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" Canvas.Top="-3" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant" />
                    </Canvas>
                    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="40" Height="21" FontSize="10"
                            Content="{Binding SaveButton.Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, FallbackValue={x:Static Localization:Strings.Save}}" 
                            Command="{Binding SaveButton.Command, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding SaveButton.CommandParameter, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and this:

```
public class SaveButton : Button {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDirtyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsDirty", typeof(bool), typeof(SaveButton));

    static SaveButton() {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SaveButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SaveButton)));
    }

    [Bindable(true), Category("Action")]
    [Localizability(LocalizationCategory.NeverLocalize)]
    public bool IsDirty {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsDirtyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsDirtyProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

and (finally):

```
<Controls:SaveButton Command="{Binding Save}" IsDirty="{Binding IsDirty}" Style="{DynamicResource SaveButtonStyle}"/>
```

The interesting part is that the `IsDirty` and `Content` bindings seem to be working properly. It's just the command routing that seems not to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are binding to property path `SaveButton.Button`, with the `TemplatedParent` as source. So your binding source is the Button you are templating,  but the `Button` does not contain a `SaveButton` property.

Try to configure the binding without `SaveButton` in the property path, like this:

```
  <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="40" Height="21" FontSize="10"
          Content="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, FallbackValue={x:Static Localization:Strings.Save}}" 
          Command="{Binding Command, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
```

Also, you can use the [{TemplateBinding..}](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742882.aspx) extension for shorter syntax.

Another thing, why do you even have `Button` control inside the template of your `SaveButton`. I think you should only retemplate visual appearance of the button, but the behavior is already there, you don't need a Button inside a Button. You could simply use the `Command` property of the Button you are templateing, no need for this command routing.

**EDIT:**

Try this template

```
<Style x:Key="SaveButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:SaveButton}">
<Style.Resources>
    <converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Style.Resources>
<Setter Property="Content" Value="Save"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Controls:SaveButton}">
            <DockPanel Width="65" Height="21" LastChildFill="True">
                <Canvas DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 0 -49 0" ZIndex="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" >
                    <Image Source="Images/green-check.png" Width="16" Height="16" Visibility="{Binding IsDirty, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" Canvas.Top="-3" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant" />
                </Canvas>
                <ContentPresenter DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>                  
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Content ("Save") of the button is set in the Style Setter. If you want some other content you can use your button like this:

```
<Controls:SaveButton Content="Something" Command="{Binding Save}" IsDirty="{Binding IsDirty}" Style="{DynamicResource SaveButtonStyle}"/>
```

Comment: <Button ... Command="{TemplateBinding Command}"
          CommandParameter="{TemplateBinding CommandParameter}" />

Would be preferable but the Command does not seem to be being handled in the ViewModel of the Window that the SaveButton is being placed on. I can see (in snoop) that the DataContext of the control is, indeed the DataContext of the Window. It's just not calling the DelegateCommand in the ViewModel.

public DelegateCommand<object> Save { get; private set; }


Save = new DelegateCommand<object>(x => {
                Debug.WriteLine("Save Clicked!");
            });

Comment: Agreed. My preference would be to re-do the visual style of the button. I am a newb so am unsure as to how to do that to simply add that check mark to the top-right of the button. If you have a suggestion for that, I am open to it.

Comment: @Flea it should be simple, just remove the Button from the template and instead of the Button put a ContentPresenter control. All should work, your ContentPresenter will display Content that is set on the button and commands that are set with bindings on your SaveButton should work.

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding you. If I change it as you suggest, I lose the entire button and only get the green check.
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Controls:SaveButton}"><DockPanel LastChildFill="True"><Canvas DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0 0 -49 0" ZIndex="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" ><Image Source="Images/green-check.png" Width="16" Height="16" Visibility="{Binding IsDirty, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" Canvas.Top="-3" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant" /></Canvas><ContentPresenter /></DockPanel></ControlTemplate>

Comment: You should set the Content on the SaveButton.  <Controls:SaveButton Content="Save" Command={Binding...   The Content that you set on the SaveButton will be presented by the ContentPresenter in the template

Comment: I apologize for taking a while with this. Other fires have come up. I am looking into your suggestions now.

Comment: When I use the sample you are suggesting, the text for the button works and the button's command is wiring appropriately but the visual aspect of the button under the green check disappears.